Addressing Variations in Stress Levels for Accurate Fatigue Analysis of Crankshafts
In analyzing the fatigue resistance of a crankshaft, how should we account for the variation in stress levels throughout its 360-degree revolution? Given that the crankshaft is subjected to different forces and stress levels at different positions, how can we ensure accurate fatigue analysis that considers the full range of motion over the desired number of cycles?
After all, everyone seems to be only working on the stress level in one angle and then converting it to fatigue analysis. But would that be enough? because I want the shaft to make a full revolution N number of times and how the fatigue analysis would understand it from the static stress analysis. I want the fatigue analysis to make the crank make full revolution N number of times and then it would give me the results for the full revolution after N cycles.

Will 2 stroke or 4 stroke make a difference?

No, it doesn't. to me all that matters is to find the correct result for the fatigue analysis for that crank
